# Find and replace multiple lines in netbeans

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-8

I need to change the content of a div in the footer of a big number of html files. I've tried the "Replace in project" function but it seems like it can't find any instances of the div I'm searching for. After some testing it seems the problem is either the line break or the tabs I used to format the code.

The part I want to find has the form:

```
<div class="class1 class2">
    Text
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the original setting, I've tried checking the boxes in different combinations as well, but to no success.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Make sure that the **File Name Patterns** field is set correctly for the files you want to modify (e.g. ***.html**, etc.). Can you update your question with a shot of the **Replace in Projects** screen showing your settings, just before you submit it?

Comment: Why does the **File Name Patterns** field contain **|.html**? Don't you want ***.html** in that field?

Comment: Thank you for noticing, sadly it wasn't the only problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately NetBeans 8.x does not support the modification of text containing line breaks when using **Edit > Replace**.

See this open bug report [Bug 148989 - [65cat] Allow linebreaks, tabs for Find/Replace actions](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=148989). Since that bug was created in 2008 for NeBeans 6.5, and the current release of NetBeans is 10.0, this enhancement is never going to be implemented in NetBeans 8.x.